# Decrease the opacity of the overlay image

Tags: html, css, templates, xhtml

I have been using the '[Big Picture](https://html5up.net/big-picture)' template for a webpage. The overlay.png does make my background lighter as it is a partially transparent blue-ish graphic that overlays intro.jpg. I tried changing the opacity and the gradient/RGBA in the css.main file so that my intro image does not go dimmer. The attempts have not been successful. Any idea to do it?

My css.main script:

```
/* Intro */

    #intro {
        background: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/intro.jpg");
        background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
        background-position: top left, bottom center;
        background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    }

/* One */

    #one {
        background: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/one.jpg");
        background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
        background-position: top left, center center;
    }

/* Two */

    #two {
        background: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/two.jpg");
        background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
        background-position: top left, center center;
    }
```

Please find the [overlay image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGNqD.png). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The CSS you posted is way too long for anyone to find the specific problem in. Can you trim it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? In your example, include the HTML for this “overlay.png” image so we can see what you’re trying to style—I couldn’t find it on the page you linked.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Done! So, if I delete the overlay, my intro image will not be washed out, but it results in a failed HTTP request because my CSS is still referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the whole overlay image and setting and manage it like:

```
#intro{
  background: url(../../images/intro.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-position: top left, bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

So you just directly manage it in settings with `opacity` ?

Comment: Many Thanks! This is the best solution.

Comment: @Bot You welcome, please validate solution and upvote if you wish

Comment: @Bot I don't see my answer accepted but nvm, if you problem is solved